# How do I take a slider value and use it as a value for time in a timed window? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, slider, raspberry-pi

I would also like the number count down to be a vertical bar that decreases in volume as if to be a bottle emptying. Is this possible?
I would also like the values set on the slider to be a timed output to 3 LEDs and to keep those LEDs on for that period of time. Is this also possible?
I am a complete noob with Python and have only just purchased a Raspberry Pi. 
Any help would be great! 
Please advise,

```
from Tkinter import *

#-----------------------------------------------    

frame_1 = None
frame_2 = None
time = 0

#-----------------------------------------------    

def create_frame_1():
    global frame_1

    frame_1 = Frame(window)
    frame_1.configure(bg='purple')

    label = Label(frame_1, text='EuroFlow E-cig Filler')
    label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    btn_nxt = Button(frame_1, bg='purple',  text='Enter', command=show_frame_2)  
    btn_nxt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=100, pady=100)

def create_frame_2():

    def show_values():
        print w1.get(), w2.get(), w3.get()

    global frame_2

    frame_2 = Frame(window)
    frame_2.configure(bg='purple')

    btn_ent = Button(frame_2, text='Enter', command=timed_window) 
    btn_ent.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_chem = Label(frame_2, bg='purple', text='Please Choose Chemical Levels')
    label_chem.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_nic = Label(frame_2, bg='purple', text='Nictonine (ml)')
    label_nic.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_glyc = Label(frame_2, bg='purple', text='Glycol (ml)')
    label_glyc.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    label_gli = Label(frame_2 , bg='purple', text='Glycerine (ml)')
    label_gli.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
    w1 = Scale(frame_2, troughcolor='green', bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    w2 = Scale(frame_2, troughcolor='green', bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    w3 = Scale(frame_2, troughcolor='green', bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
    w3.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

    btn_back = Button(frame_2, text='Back', command=show_frame_1) 
    btn_back.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

#-----------------------------------------------    

def show_frame_1():
    frame_2.pack_forget()
    window.title('EuroFlow')
    frame_1.pack()

def show_frame_2():
    frame_1.pack_forget()
    window.title('Process Screen')
    frame_2.pack()



#-----------------------------------------------    

def timed_window():
    global time

    time = 500    #------ I want this value to be a sum of the 3 values set on the sliders

    def countdown():
        global time

        if time > 0:
            time -= 1
            lab.config(text=str(time))
            subwindow.after(100, countdown) # 100 miliseconds
        else:
            subwindow.destroy()

    subwindow = Toplevel(window)
    subwindow.title('countdown')
    subwindow.configure(bg='purple')

    lab = Label(subwindow, bg='purple', text=str(time))
    lab.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    subwindow.after(100, countdown) # 100 miliseconds

#-----------------------------------------------    

window = Tk()

create_frame_1()
create_frame_2()

show_frame_1()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As written, your question is too vague. It seems like you're asking "is it possible", and the answer is "yes". Is there some specific part of the problem that you need help with?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to make the three that will be set onto each scale values that can make an LED come on for that amount of time. For example if the first slider was set to 20, I would like the first LED to come on for 20 seconds. If the second slider was set to 15, come on for 15 seconds etc. Please advise. Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can get the value from each slider by doing w1.get() however that will only work if the sliders are declared globally (bad practice) or if you re-code the app to work as a class, and make the sliders belong to the class.

a class is intended to hold structure, so you can define the structure using a class and the  instantiate it, to make this clearer, most tkinter widgets such as frames and labels are examples of classes.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        #create window
        self.window = Tk()

        #create frame 1
        self.frame_1 = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame_1.configure(bg='purple')

        label = Label(self.frame_1, text='EuroFlow E-cig Filler')
        label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        btn_nxt = Button(self.frame_1, bg='purple',  text='Enter', command=self.show_frame_2)  
        btn_nxt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=100, pady=100)

        #create frame 2
        self.frame_2 = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame_2.configure(bg='purple')

        btn_ent = Button(self.frame_2, text='Enter', command=self.timed_window) 
        btn_ent.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        label_chem = Label(self.frame_2, bg='purple', text='Please Choose Chemical Levels')
        label_chem.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        label_nic = Label(self.frame_2, bg='purple', text='Nictonine (ml)')
        label_nic.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        label_glyc = Label(self.frame_2, bg='purple', text='Glycol (ml)')
        label_glyc.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        label_gli = Label(self.frame_2 , bg='purple', text='Glycerine (ml)')
        label_gli.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.w1 = Scale(self.frame_2, troughcolor='green', bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
        self.w1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.w2 = Scale(self.frame_2, troughcolor='green', bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
        self.w2.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.w3 = Scale(self.frame_2, troughcolor='green', bg='purple', from_=30, to=0, orient=VERTICAL, resolution=0.5)
        self.w3.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        btn_back = Button(self.frame_2, text='Back', command=self.show_frame_1) 
        btn_back.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        #start by showing the first frame
        self.show_frame_1()

    def show_frame_1(self):
        self.frame_2.pack_forget()
        self.window.title('EuroFlow')
        self.frame_1.pack()

    def show_frame_2(self):
        self.frame_1.pack_forget()
        self.window.title('Process Screen')
        self.frame_2.pack()

    def timed_window(self):
        t1 = self.w1.get() # get each of the slider values
        t2 = self.w2.get()
        t3 = self.w3.get()
        self.time = t1 + t2 + t3 # add the values together

        self.subwindow = Toplevel(self.window)
        self.subwindow.title('countdown')
        self.subwindow.configure(bg='purple')

        self.lab = Label(self.subwindow, bg='purple', text=str(self.time))
        self.lab.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.subwindow.after(100, self.countdown) # 100 miliseconds

    def countdown(self):
        if self.time > 0:
            self.time -= 1
            self.lab.config(text=str(self.time))
            self.subwindow.after(100, self.countdown) # 100 miliseconds
        else:
            self.subwindow.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.window.mainloop()
```

i have modified most of your code to use a class based structure, however there will be at least one flaw in this program in that if the values add up to a decimal as opposed to a whole number i'm not sure how your countdown will handle it.

Comment: Hi James, I am a new beginner to coding, could you tell me what exactly a class is, how to make my sliders belong to one, and maybe some sort of example? Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks Ally

Comment: Thanks very much for the help James only small snag is I can't get it to run and being very new to this can't exactly understand why. I keep getting this error message when I try to run it. Again, any help would be hugely appreciated :)




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/HOPE THIUS WORKS.py", line 3, in <module>
    class euroflow():
  File "/home/pi/HOPE THIUS WORKS.py", line 9, in euroflow
    self.frame_1 = Frame(self.window)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: sorry, when i pasted it the code didn't indent properly everything from creating the first frame down to subwindow.destroy() was supposed to be one indentation further in

Comment: arghhh forgot about indents

Comment: works perfectly thanks James, starting to get the hang of this now